# Posting data to database with Alamofire failed

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire

I am having an issue with posting data using Alamofire. I am making a comment box. I grab user data from the server and post his comment using his information with his comment on the article id, but when I post it sends no information to the server! I see only empty data.

The user data are successfully loaded from the server and I can see it in the console using the print accountDetails but after posting nothing is shown!

Breakpoint gives valid data too!

[image]

My code:

```swift
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    var data: JSON?
    var userData = [JSON]()
    var accountDetails = ["name": "", "email": "", "phone": ""]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CommentTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var CommentTXTField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getUserData()
        print("Account:\(accountDetails)")
        
        if let id = Helper.getUserId() {
            ContactBtn.isHidden = false
        } else {
            ContactBtn.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func AddCommentBTN(_ sender: Any) {
        let commentTXT = CommentTXTField.text
        print(commentTXT!)
        
        let name =   self.accountDetails["name"]
        let mobile =  self.accountDetails["phone"]
        let email =  self.accountDetails["email"]
        let articleId = data!["id"].string!
        
        API.AddComment(articleId: articleId, name: name!, email: email!, phone: mobile!, message: commentTXT!) { (error: Error?, success: Bool) in
            if success {
                print("Registerd Successfuly")
            } else {
                print("Faile To Comment")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getUserData() {
        guard let UserId = Helper.getUserMob() else { return }
        let url = "https://site.co/apis/getprofile.php?mob=" + UserId
        AF.request(url).validate().responseJSON { [self] response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                if let id = json["data"]["id"].string {
                    print("id: \(id)")
                }
                self.accountDetails["name"] = json["data"]["name"].string
                self.accountDetails["email"] = json["data"]["email"].string
                self.accountDetails["phone"] = json["data"]["phone"].string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

API.AddComment function

```js
    class func AddComment(articleId: String, name: String, email: String, message: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ success: Bool)->Void){
        let url = URLs.AddComment
       
       let parameters = [
           "article_id": articleId,
           "name": name,
           "email": email,
            "message": message
       
       ] 

        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default , headers: nil)
           .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
           .responseJSON { response in
               
               switch response.result
               {
               case .failure(let error):
                completion(error, false)
                   print(error)
               case .success(let value):
                   let json = JSON(value)
                   if let id = json["data"]["id"].string {
                       print("id: \(id)")
                    completion(nil, true)

                   }
                   
               }
           
       }
        
    }
```

Comment: looks like, an object is deallocating after making a request and not waiting for a response from server, that's why u see data in sever not at client side.

Comment: @SachinVsSachin and what is the best solution for that ?

Comment: Hold the object.

Comment: Based off the screenshot with the breakpoint, it looks like all the data being passed to the `AddComment` function is valid, so I would suspect the issue resides inside that function. Can you share the `API.AddComment` function?

Comment: @mwahlig I added it on the main thread

Comment: @mwahlig would you please advice ?

Comment: Is your API expecting the parameters to be encoded in the url or as JSON in the request body? If it's the latter, you need use the `JSONParameterEncoder.default` as your request encoding. Thats the only potential issue I can see based on the `API.AddComment` function you shared.